# Is there a continuous compilation plugin for Visual Studio Code like Godbolt's Compiler Explorer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, ninja

I wanted something that would compile automatically after a given number of (milli)seconds and display the results in the "Problems" tab.

The current behavior is to statically analyze every file on itself, which typically misses a lot of context (macros primarily) and produces a quasi-infinite array of false positives that make its use typically very difficult, at least on my particular use cases.

I found [Matt Ever's Compiler Explorer plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MatthewEvers.compiler-explorer) but it suffers from the original problem: it analizes each source file without context.

I do not really need to see the generated assembly side-by-side, although having that would be fantastic as I could stop using objdump for that purpose on a terminal.

The main requirement here is really to not take my hands off the keyboard to issue a build command - and respective mouse moves etc. I need context-dependent squiggles, tightly integrated with the build system I am currently using.

I am aiming primarily at C++ with CMake so a good solution would take advantage of the output this build system generates. I would not mind if the solution is specific to a single cmake generator as Make or Ninja.

Suggestions and even DIY solutions are very very welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Compiler explorer is open source so you can write an extension that behaves the same.

Comment: @rioV8 Matt Evers plugin cited above does exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're looking for a Language Server Protocol (LSP) plugin, especially since you don't care strongly about having side-by-side assembly. Check out [clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) or https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp.

If you're using the clangd plugin, you can use the [`EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) CMake property to generate a compile_commands.json file, which clangd uses to know how to compile your files.

Comment: how do you misunderstand the question this badly? [is it possible to learn this power](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/is-it-possible-to-learn-this-power)?